# createReactionCollector not working in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm attempting to create a reaction collector on an embed my bot sends, the code is below:

```
import { TextChannel, DMChannel, Emoji, Client, Message, EmojiResolvable, ReactionEmoji } from "discord.js";

var awaitReaction = (message: Message, originalAuthor: string) => {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        await message.react('✅')
        await message.react('❌')

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            console.log(['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === originalAuthor)
            return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === originalAuthor;
        };

        var collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 200000 });

        collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Result: ${collected.first().emoji.name}`));
    });
};

export { awaitReaction }
```

When I react to one of the reactions, nothing appears in the console and the end event is not fired.

Answer (score 2):

Was unrelated to code, forgot to add the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent.