# DISCORD JS v13 createReactionCollector "collect" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

## Introduce

I want to use page generation from [discord.js-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-pagination) in discord.js v13.
The source code use `createReactionCollector` but `collect` doesn't work.

[image: discord preview]

## In Detail

The two reaction buttons are displayed correctly. It also runs the timeout correctly and the two buttons are removed after 12000ms.

The problem is that there is no response when I press the reaction button.
**"collect" doesn't work.**

I can't believe that "end" is executed, but "collect" is not.
Could anyone give me a clue?

### Source code

```
 static async paginationEmbed(msg: Message, pages:MessageEmbed[], emojiList = ['⏪', '⏩'], timeout = 12000)
 {
    if (!pages) throw new Error('Pages are not given.');
    if (emojiList.length !== 2) throw new Error('Need two emojis.');
    let page = pages.length - 1;
    const curPage = await msg.channel.send({ embeds: [pages[page].setFooter(`Page ${page + 1} / ${pages.length}`)]});

    for (const emoji of emojiList) await curPage.react(emoji);
    const filter = (reaction:MessageReaction, user:User) => {
        return true;
    }
    const reactionCollector = curPage.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: timeout });

    reactionCollector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        console.log("I want to show this!!")

        reaction.users.remove(msg.author);
        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
            case emojiList[0]:
                page = page > 0 ? --page : pages.length - 1;
                break;
            case emojiList[1]:
                page = page + 1 < pages.length ? ++page : 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        curPage.edit({ embeds: [pages[page].setFooter(`Page ${page + 1} / ${pages.length}`)]});

    });

    reactionCollector.on('end', () => {
        if (!curPage.deleted) {
            curPage.reactions.removeAll()
        }
    });

    return curPage;
}
```

---

## Enviroment

discord.js@13.1.0
(get by `npm ls`)

## Addition

My Client is following:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
 intents: ['GUILD_VOICE_STATES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILDS']
 });
```

[createReactionCollector not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987922/createreactioncollector-not-triggering)

Comment: What are your intents?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I want to enable "collect" when I press the reaction button.

Comment: I'm sorry, not the goal of this. I know that was confusing. I mean what are the intents you provided for your client?

Comment: I see. Does "client" mean https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client? Does "intent" mean https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents? Sorry, I am beginner.

Comment: Sorry, MrMythical. I understood your means.
`intents: ['GUILD_VOICE_STATES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILDS']` This is my intent.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Mr Mythical! The topic help me.

Comment: You can upvote the answer there it helped

Answer (score 2):

I can solve this problem.

> Was unrelated to code, forgot to add the GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS intent.

[createReactionCollector not working in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025233/createreactioncollector-not-working-in-discord-js)

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
 intents: ['GUILD_VOICE_STATES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS'],
});
```