Discord.js - Reaction collector doesnt seem to work, any idea why?
Reaction collector does not seem to work for me , i am expecting to be able to collect reactions on a message or embed.
Here is the slash command i created
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
     .setName('ping')
     .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
 async execute(interaction) {
     try {
         console.log(`User ${interaction.user.tag} used the /ping command.`);

         await interaction.reply('React with any emoji within 15 seconds.');

         // Get the message object
         const message = await interaction.fetchReply();

         // Reaction collector 
         const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === interaction.user.id;
         const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

         collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
             console.log(`User ${user.tag} reacted with ${reaction.emoji.name}`);
         });

         collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
             console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} reactions. Reason: ${reason}`);
         });

                     // Log when collector starts
                     console.log('Reaction collector started.');

     } catch (error) {
         console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
     }
 },
};

and the results i get in console after reacting:
User xxxx used the /ping command. Collected 0 items. Reason: time
I have verified permissions on the developer site:
Permissions are: application commands, bot, manage messages, send messages, read messages.
I have many other slash commands and functions working.
I have tried this with an embed and regular message. I have tried to listen for any reaction, as i thought it could be the type of thumbs up.
Not sure what to test next or if i am missing something obvious
Looking at the discord guide this should work:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions

Your problem is this piece of code here:


const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
   filter: collectorFilter,
   time: 15000, // 15 seconds
});



You have created a component collector and are therefore collecting component interactions (and not reactions). To be clear, components are buttons, select menus, etc (more info here). You need to use the createReactionCollector() function instead. Example syntax is listed on the page you have linked here.

Thankyou for your input , i noticed this error a few days ago, and did not update it here, i have simplified the code and corrected that error quite a bit, but i am still not collecting any reactions to any emoji.
I edited my original post with the current code, is there anything else you can see as an issue?

@AdamH Having reviewed your updated code, I see that you have simply written filter for the collector. Perhaps try filter: filter instead? I vaguely recall running into this issue in the past and this may have been the fix. If this does not work out, I can try to delve further into intents/permissions.

@AdamH I noticed you mentioned various permissions in your post, but have you added all of the appropriate intents? I did some quick searching and came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69682144/22268909

Thankyou both good points.
i changed the reaction collector to this with the same results:
// Reaction collector
         const reactFilter = () => true;
         const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter: reactFilter, time: 15000 });

and i have the following intents:
GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions

@AdamH If you want to try without a filter, you can remove the filter keyword-value pair altogether. That is probably the best way to confirm the filter not being a problem here. You can also try using the messageReactionAdd event listener (see this page) to see if the event is firing at all when a reaction is added. If the event does not fire, then perhaps the issue is related to permissions/channel visibility/intents rather than in the code you have provided.

Thankyou for all your help, removing the filter and adding the guildmessages intent has resolved my issue.
I assumed that guildmessageReactions intent would be enough.

I'm happy to hear that you were able to get it working. Thanks for letting me know about the issue as well. If you still want to use the filter, you can probably do so now!
